# excel function syntax calling error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-udf

I've created this function:

```
Public Function getLastCellValue(ByVal row As Integer, ByVal column As String) As String
If (Cells(row, column).Value = "") Then
    getLastCellValue = getLastCellValue(row - 1, column)
Else: getLastCellValue = Cells.Item(row, column).Value
End If
End Function
```

When I use it in a cell this:

```
=getLastCellValue(1,"C")
```

Excel tells me that the function contains an error and focuses on the second parameter: `"C"`.

I'm going crazy because I do not understand the mistake.

Comment: Make sure your Excel language is using the comma (`,`) to separate functions parameters; if your name tells me something about your nationality, I guess you're using an Italian/Spanish system (which means you should separate inputs by semi-column (`;`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>`Cells(row, column)` expects numeric parameter values</s>. If you mean to refer to cell addresses (like, "A1") then it might be simpler to use `Range` instead.

That said I strongly recommend taking this implementation over to [Code Review](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com) once you get it to work as expected, ...I'd have several things to point out ;)

---

Your code works *as is* on my machine. My bet is on [@Matteo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283027/vba-excel-function-issue/29283233#comment46764229_29283027)

> *Make sure your Excel language is using the comma (,) to separate functions parameters; if your name tells me something about your nationality, I guess you're using an Italian/Spanish system (which means you should separate inputs by semi-column (;)*

Comment: Wrong, it takes the letter as well.

Comment: Cells() can use a column's string name.  I didn't think it would work either when I saw someone else using it on this board until I tried it.  I'm using 2007 for reference.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ The IntelliSense calls the parameters `[RowIndex]` and `[ColumnIndex]`... damn Microsoft!

Comment: Moreover, the function crashes on the beginning, it doesn't enter the code. I guess he should separate values by semi-columns (`;`) and not commas (`,`), it should be related to the operating system

Comment: Exactly, damn Microsoft :)

Comment: Mat, you can report the comment on your answer body to make it the correct one ;)

Comment: The problem was the comma. The correct usage of function require the semicolumn on my Excel 2011 for Mac, Italian version. MatteoNNZ you win!